# Cannot find parent service in nested structural directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I'm using Angular 8 to build my little application.
In my app, I have 2 structural directives:

- `parent.directive.ts` :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[parent]',
  providers: [
    DemoService
  ]
})
export class ParentDirective implements OnInit {

   public constructor(protected viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
                     protected templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, 
                     public demoService: DemoService) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.demoService
    .name = 'parent';

    this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }
}
```

- child.directive.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[child]',
  providers: [
    DemoService
  ]
})
export class ChildDirective implements OnInit {

   public constructor(protected viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
                     protected templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, 
                     public demoService: DemoService, 
                     @SkipSelf() public parentDemoService: DemoService) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.demoService
    .name = 'parent';

    console.log(this.parentDemoService.name);
  }
}
```

My 2 directives all initialize a `DemoService`, however, in `child.directive.ts`, I also want to access to the `DemoService` which is in `parent.directive.ts`.

Therefore, in `child.directive.ts`, I declare the DI as below:

```
 public constructor(protected viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
                     protected templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, 
                     public demoService: DemoService, 
                     @SkipSelf() public parentDemoService: DemoService) {
  }
```

This is what I used in the html page:

```
<div *parent>
   <div>Inside parent</div>
      <div *child>
        <div>Inside child</div>
      </div>

    <div *parent>
   <div>Inside parent parent</div>
      <div *child>
        <div>Inside child</div>
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>

   </div> 
</div>
```

I expect that I can access the `DemoService` in the parent directive through `parentDemoService` instance, but I received the following error:

**ERROR
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ParentDirective -> DemoService]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ParentDirective -> DemoService]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for DemoService!**

I already put my demo code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redplane-structural-directive).

Can anyone help me on this one ?
Thank you.

P/s : **I want to provide new instance for each directive. That's why I used provider in the parent and child directive**

Because some people dont understand my question (perhaps it is not clear enough I think), I updated 2 images to describe my problem.

Let say, the `DemoService` has a counter variable, start from 1 in parent and can be increased by child structural directives.

This is my expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

Error messages states angular is not able to inject the service required for parent directive. You should help angular to identify the service required by specifying provider details. There are couple of ways to specify.

Solution:
Introduce `providers: [DemoService]` in app.module.ts will resolve.

Comment: Actually I want to provide new instance for each directive. That's why I used provider in the `parent` and `child` directive.

Answer (score 0):

For this to achieve you need to restructure the whole application.

Create a `ParentModule` with two services `ShareService` and `DemoService` as providers and declare, export `ParentDirective` in this module and import this in `RootModule`.

And provide `DemoService` in `ChildDirective`.

Now Instantiate `DemoService` in `ShareService` and make this instance equal to `ParentDirective` instance, 
So you can access this `ParentDirective` instance in the `ChildDirective` through the `ShareService`.

Check this out: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redplane-structural-directive-vj3nfg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one so I'm going to start by saying that I'm fairly new to angular and still have a long way to go. But I love learning so I tried to understand your problem and implement a solution for you using the Official Documentation and example. Therefore, use the following implementation at your own discretion!

Depending on what exactly you want to do, the app needs some changes in the structure. As far as I know, providing the service in the component level, limits the service to that component and won't allow you to achieve your goal. Here I have two solutions for you:

1- Define `DemoService` and a `ChildDemoService` that extends the `DemoService` in the `'root'` and inject your `DemoService` to both parent and child directives and inject the `ChildDemoService` into your child directive only. This way you'll have two instances of the `DemoService` in both components but those instances will share the same state and can be edited through both parent and child directives. You will also have a `childDemoService` that is only accessible to the child (not sure if you need this one).

I've updated your code in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/specialized-providers) to reflect this. I have included meaningful `console.log()`s for you so don't forget to open your browser inspector!

For more information refer to [Angular Official Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#scenario-specialized-providers) and play around with [Their Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aeymqapdvmg).

2- Create a separate modules that declares your child and parent directives and provide your service in that module so that the instances of your service are only accessible via these two directives and the directives themselves can be accessible anywhere you want them to be accessed in the app (Depending on your implementation)

Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns since this was an intriguing question for me.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Actually I inject the `DemoService` from parent to child because I want the child to access to information belongs to its **parent** only. If a `parent` in side the `parent`. The service lifetime of 2 parents and parentService in their child **MUST** be different.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Redplane Yes, you can achieve this by making a `parentModule`.
check my answer, and let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @Alex, I tried your solution on stackblitz. Actually that is not the result I expected.
I already made 2 pictures about your solution and the expected result.
This is your result https://i.imgur.com/Ou4kNKN.png , and this is the expected one: https://i.imgur.com/PDXq5f0.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was try to provide new instance of service via structural directive (*) providers. It's angular limitation.
My solution is to crate new **not structural** directive on the same level as *parent to provide service for nested directives.

```
<div *parent parentToProvideService>
   <div>Inside parent</div>
      <div *child>
        <div>Inside child</div>
      </div>      
</div>

@Directive({
  selector: '[parentToProvideService]',
  providers: [
    DemoService
  ]
})
export class ParentToProvideServiceDirective implements OnInit {

   public constructor(public demoService: DemoService) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    // some code
  }
}
```